# Do i need to delete objects that i set in class member when i replace them?

Tags: c++

I have the following:

```
class Manager{
public:
    void update(list<Employe> employees){
        employees_ = employees;
    }
private:
    list<Employe> employees_;
};
```

do i need to delete old employees in the end of update method?

Comment: It should say `Employee` instead of `Employe`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no "old employees". In this case a

```
list<Employee>::operator = (const list<Employee> & source)
```

will be called. If you didn't defined one, the default one will copy raw contents of the instance passed as a parameter (employees) to the field (employees_).

Now suppose, that list contains a pointer to a dynamically allocated memory. In such case a reference to that memory will be lost and it will leak.

The correct solution is either to check, if operator = is overloaded correctly (for example all standard containers already has it implemented) or implement it by yourself (pseudocode):

```
void list<Employee>::operator = (const list<Employee> & source)
{
    freeContents();
    for (int i = 0; i < source.size(); i++)
        add(source.getItem(i));
}
```

---

**Edit:**

If the list is actually a std::list, it will handle the assignment correctly, so in this case the answer is: yes, the list itself will be freed automatically. Its contents, however, that's another story.

Comment: can you please explain this - " So if you allocate memory dynamically inside the list class, it may leak."

Comment: I use std::list , so i dont allocate dynamic memory in the list.

Comment: It would be wise to note that in your code either by #using namespace std or std::list. Anyone can implement a class called "list".

Answer (score 1):

In C++, the assignment operator copies the LHS to the RHS, and takes care of destroying whatever is currently occupying the LHS.

In the code

```
void update(list<Employe> employees){
    employees_ = employees;
}
```

after the function has executed, the previous contents of `employees_` will have been destroyed, and `employees_` will now contain a *copy* of the parameter `employees`.

To make this more efficient, you can eliminate the copy:

```
employees_ = std::move(employees);    // C++11
```

or

```
std::swap(employees_, employees);     // C++03
```

In the first case, the contents of `employees_` will be discarded, and the contents of `employees` will be *moved* to `employees_`, leaving `employees` empty.

In the second case, the contents of `employees_` and `employees` will be *swapped*, so that when the function returns the original contents of `employees_` will be discarded.

Answer (score 0):

No, you don't, they will be destroyed automatically. Because they are stored on automatic storage (stack)

Also a little improvement:

```
void update(const list<Employe> & employees){ //pass by reference, not by value
    employees_ = employees; //old values are automatically destroyed and 
   // copies of new values are added, preserving the original values in passed container
}
```

Comment: What do you mean automatic storage. i am familiar with heap and stack?

Comment: @user1495181 "stack" is a word many use when they mean to say "automatic storage"

Comment: Regarding the pass by reference- isnt it a problem , becasue when the calling method ended(the method that create the list and call to update) than the list that was built in the calling method dosnt exist any more?

Comment: @user1495181: If you are talking about `employees_;` - no, because it will contain copies from the passed list

Comment: The core problem is, that no assignment (ad hoc) will happen here. If there is no list<T>::operator = implemented, raw contents of the parameter will be copied to the field. If a list class allocates memory to store its contents, it won't be automatically released and it may leak.

Comment: @Spook: it's obvious that he uses `std::list` which has operator=

Comment: He may, he may not. Until it is not stated clearly, we have to assume, that the class is written by himself. I don't like guessing, what author had in his mind :)

Answer (score 0):

In C++11, I would suggest you to use `std::move` as:

```
void update(list<Employee> employees) //NOTE :  pass by value
{
    employees_ = std::move(employees);
}
```

Note that the argument is passed by value, not passed by reference. This means, when you write this,

```
update({e1,e2,e3,e3});
```

then the *temporary* list created from argument, is *moved* to the member variable. In this way, you avoid making a copy of the temporary object (which is going to get destroyed, anyway).

If you use `list<Employee> const & employees` as parameter, then you wouldn't be able to `std::move` the resource of the temporary object created from the above call.